# Setting up a cronjob on Google Compute Engine

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-compute-engine, debian-buster

I am new to setting up cronjobs and I'm trying to do it on a virtual machine in google compute engine. After a bit of research, I found this StackOverflow question: [Running Python script at Regular intervals using Cron in Virtual Machine (Google Cloud Platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848163/running-python-script-at-regular-intervals-using-cron-in-virtual-machine-google)

As per the answer, I managed to enter the `crontab -e` edit mode and set up a test cronjob like `10 8 * * * /usr/bin/python /scripts/kite-data-pull/dataPull.py`. I also checked the system time, which was in UTC, and entered the time according to that.

The step I'm supposed to take, as per the answer, is to run `sudo systemctl restart cron` which is throwing an error for me:

```
sudo systemctl restart cron
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to set up this cronjob correctly?

Comment: Can you try: "sudo service cron reload" or "/etc/init.d/cron reload" command?

Comment: I tried `sudo service cron relead` and it gave me this output `[ ok ] Reloading configuration files for periodic command scheduler: cron.` I'll check if the script runs in 10 mins

Comment: The cronjob did not run, is there anything else that I can try? If it helps, my script is written in python 3 and it runs if I do a `python dataPull.py`

Comment: Do you know if it has permission issue ? check the permission. Also verify if you need to add sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit a cron jobs with `crontab -e` and inset a line:

`* * * * * echo test123 > /your_homedir_path/file.log`

That will write `test123` every minute into file.log file.

Then do `tail if` and wait a couple minutes. You should see `test123` lines appearing in the file (and screen).

If it runs try running your python file but first make your .py file executable with "`chmod +x script.py`"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61591830/12257250) you can find my reply to similar question.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the step with making the file executable by running the `chmod +x` command

Comment: Thanks for confirmation ! Glad I could help :)